# How to redirect multiple older application to newer version application in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, url-routing, custom-error-handling

```
My IIS server has multiple application in single website. Here am planned to turn off(remove) the older application from IIS and redirect to newer version. 

For example:

www.mydomain.com/demos/2.0/ (older version)
www.mydomain.com/demos/3.0/ (older version)
www.mydomain.com/demos/3.5/ (older version)
www.mydomain.com/demos/4.0/ (newer version)
```

I have checked this url rewrite module and others  using wildcard. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Create rule to rewrite or redirect (`type="Rewrite"` or `type="Redirect"`) the request:

```
<rule name="GoToNewVersion" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="demos/[23]\../" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/demos/4.0/" />
</rule>
```